# Perl6 ハッシュの配列の作り方

Tags: perl

Perl6 で配列のサイズが1しかないハッシュの配列を作りたいのですが、どういう訳か、ペア(Pair)の配列が作られてしまいます。

Perl6 ではこれが普通なのでしょうか、それとも私のプログラムの書き方が間違っているのでしょうか。ご指導の程よろしくお願いいたします。

```
my @list = [
    { name => "foo", id => 1 }
];
@list.perl.say;
```

上の出力（ペアの配列）

```
[:id(1), :name("foo")]
```

期待する出力（ハッシュの配列）

```
[{:id(1), :name("foo")}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ }` の末尾に `,` を付けると、ハッシュとして認識されます

```
my @list = [
    { name => "foo", id => 1 },
];
@list.perl.say;
```